# Two table rows to one with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Is it possible with CSS to change the appearance of a normal table like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Row1Cell1 | Row1Cell2 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Row2Cell1 | Row2Cell2 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Row3Cell1 | Row3Cell2 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Row4Cell1 | Row4Cell2 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Row5Cell1 | Row5Cell2 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Row6Cell1 | Row6Cell2 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Into this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Row1Cell1 | Row1Cell2 | Row2Cell1 | Row2Cell2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Row3Cell1 | Row3Cell2 | Row4Cell1 | Row4Cell2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Row5Cell1 | Row5Cell2 | Row6Cell1 | Row6Cell2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

What I want to do is render two (or perhaps even three) `<tr>`s on the same visual row.
I would like to accomplish this without using javascript if possible.

regards Oskar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know how wide your `<tr>`s are you can use this:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1 1</td>
            <td>1 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2 1</td>
            <td>2 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3 1</td>
            <td>3 2</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- more stuff here -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr {
    float: left;
}

tr:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

It lets the `<tr>`s float but breaks every now and then. You can control when this happens using the `:nth-child`-selector. In this case (`:nth-child(3n+1)`) it breaks after every third row. Using `2n+1` breaks after every second row and finally `n+1` brings back your original order from the beginning. I hope this helps.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/3USN2/)

<sup>A note: I tested this in Safari, Chrome and Firefox but not in IE - didn't have time to start the VM.</sup>

PS: If you know how wide your `<tr>`s are you can do it just with `tr { float: left; }` and by setting the overall width of the table so that 1, 2 or 3 rows would have enough space horizontally.